# using htaccess for good SEO links

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I building a Web forum whose link looks like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1/website/comments.php?topic_id=2/create+good+seo+links
```

The link generating the link looks like this

```
<a href="comments.php?topic_id=<?php echo (int)($forum_topic['topic_id']); >/<?php echo urlencode(htmlspecialchars($forum_topic['topic_head'])); > ">
```

Question: How can I make the link look like

```
http://127.0.0.1/website/comments/topic/create-good-seo-links/2
```

I tried apply this code in .htaccess file :

```
   RewiteEngine on
   RewriteBase /website
   RewriteRule ^comments/([a-zA-Z0-9_-)/([0-9]+)\.php$ comments.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket and limiter in your RewriteRule `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+`

You also need to change the id pointer to `$2` since it's matching the second regex rule.

Comment: If I change the id to 2, can it work for all integers ? Since it's a forum and many topics will be created.

Comment: You're not changing the id to 2, you're changing the id to `$2` which will match the `([0-9]+)` rule.

Answer (score 0):

You would need the htaccess rules something like this:

```
RewiteEngine on
RewriteRule ^website/comments/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])/([0-9]+)$ comments.php?topic_id=$3
```

which will redirect the friendly URL to the normal script file, `$3` being the 3rd set of brackets in the first part of the rewrite rule (i.e. the number).

So then you need to change the output to this:

```
<a href="comments.php?topic_id=<?php echo $forum_topic['name']; ?>/<?php echo urlencode(htmlspecialchars($forum_topic['topic_head'])); ?>/<?php echo (int)$forum_topic['topic_id'] ?>">
```

Note I wasn't sure about the `$forum_topic['name']` so you'll need to check what that variable is called in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewiteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subdir/comments/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])/([0-9]+)$ comments.php?topic_id=$3
```

If You Want To Do Good SEO Use Some Demand Keywords In URL
example
If You have Downloading Portal

```
www.domain.com/games/mobile-os/game-name/id/page.html
```

it will help you to get good rank in google

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I make sure Keywords are part of the URL ? It's a forum and users create topics with title they want. Is there a way around this ?

Comment: www.domain.com/forum-name/topic-name/by-user/page1.html
something like this
use **-** instead of **_**